# Could not resolve dependencies with maven's hierarchy and a custom in-project repository

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem with maven's hierarchy and a custom in-project repository.

This is the parent POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-1.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groud-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-id</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        ..
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>my-common-library</module>
        <module>my-module-1</module>
        <module>my-module-2</module>
    </modules>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-repo</id>
            <name>local repo ${}</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/../repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

the folder structure in the main project is:

```
my-common-library
my-module-1
my-module-2
repo
 └───com
     └───3rd-part
         ├───3rd-part-lib-1
         │   └───4.0
         ├───3rd-part-lib-2
         │   └───4.0
         ├───3rd-part-lib-3
         │   └───4.0
         ├───3rd-part-lib-4
         │   └───4.0
         └───3rd-part-lib-5
             └───4.0
pom.xml
```

I installed the 'my-common-library' module in the local repository using the 'clean source:jar install' command and checking in the ${user.home}/.m2/repository/ folder that the installation was successful (it was).

```
groud-id
    └───my-common-library
        │   maven-metadata-local.xml
        │
        ├───3.3
        │       m2e-lastUpdated.properties
        │       my-common-library-3.3-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated
        │       my-common-library-3.3-sources.jar.lastUpdated
        │       my-common-library-3.3.jar.lastUpdated
        │       my-common-library-3.3.pom.lastUpdated
        │
        └───4.0.0
                m2e-lastUpdated.properties  
                my-common-library-4.0.0-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated
                my-common-library-4.0.0-sources.jar
                my-common-library-4.0.0.jar
                my-common-library-4.0.0.jar.lastUpdated
                my-common-library-4.0.0.pom
                my-common-library-4.0.0.pom.lastUpdated
                _remote.repositories
```

Trying to package the module 'my-module-1' via 'clean verify' command gives me an error that it cannot find the dependency 'my-common-library' in the 'local-repo' repository, completely ignoring that this dependency was on the local repository, specifically the error was:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-module-1: Could not resolve dependencies for project groud-id:my-module-1:war:4.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at groud-id:my-common-library:jar:4.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for groud-id:my-common-library:jar:4.0.0: Failure to find groud-id:parent-id:pom:4.0.0 in file://D:\dev-customers\customer\workspace\parent-id\my-module-1/../repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Honestly, this is the first time that this situation has happened to me, perhaps because it is the first time that I have tried to use Maven's hierarchical structure.

Maven: 3.3.9 (Eclipse EMBEDDED)
Java: JDK 1.8.0_271

Comment: it is a bit hard to follow your example, but it is trying to look for a `pom`? `Failure to find groud-id:LiveDocsES4:pom:1.0.0...`

Comment: @Eugene yes it is, but i dont know why it can resolve it in ${user.home}/.m2/repository/ folder. Files are there !

Comment: both the `jar` and `pom` are there, right?

Comment: @Eugene yep, ive edited with all the local repository structur via 'tree' command. all files are there !

Comment: Why is this repository with this `file://${project.basedir}/../repo`  needed? Please make an example project on github or alike ....

Comment: You said you installed `my-common-library`, but what about `groud-id:LiveDocsES4:pom:1.0.0`?

Comment: @JFabianMeier LiveDocsES4 is the parent-id that I tried to obscure in a clumsy way, I updated the example

Comment: @khmarbaise unfortunately it is not possible for me to upload more than this, I need the repository in order not to install third-party dependencies directly using the "mvn install: install-file" command

Comment: What kind of 3rd party dependencies? Furthermore I strongly recommend to use a repository manager ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is clearly stated in the error message:

> Failure to find groud-id:parent-id:pom:4.0.0 in
> file://D:\dev-customers\customer\workspace\parent-id\my-module-1/../repo

This means that didn't do a `mvn install` for the parent pom. That needs to be in a repository to be able to correctly resolve dependencies for the common module.

If you do a `mvn install` from the parent directory, it will first install the parent pom and then all child modules as described by the modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>my-common-library</module>
    <module>my-module-1</module>
    <module>my-module-2</module>
</modules>
```

You can also do `mvn install -N` in the parent folder, which will only install the parent pom, and not all the child modules.